# Python: remember line index when reading lines from text file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm extracting data in a loop from a text file between two strings with Python 3.6. I've got multiple strings of which I would like to extract data between those strings, see code below:

```
for i  in range(0,len(strings1)):

    with open('infile.txt','r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:

        copy = False

        for line in infile:
            if line == strings1[i]:
                copy = True
            elif line == strings2[i]:
                copy = False
            elif copy:
                outfile.write(line)
                continue
```

To decrease the processing time of the loop, I would like to modify my code such that after it has extracted data between two strings, let's say strings1[1] and strings2[1], it remembers the line index of strings2[1] and starts the next iteration of the loop at that line index. Therefore it doesn't have to read the whole file during each iteration. The string lists are build such that the previous strings will never occur after a current string, so modifying my code to what I want won't break the loop.

Does anyone how to do this?

===========================================================================

EDIT:

I've got a file in a format such as:

> the first line
>
> bla bla bla
>
> FIRST some string 1
>
> 10 10
>
> 15 20
>
> 5 2.5
>
> SECOND some string 2
>
> bla bla bla
>
> bla bla bla
>
> FIRST some string 3
>
> 10 10
>
> 15 20
>
> 5 2.5
>
> SECOND some string 4

The file goes on like this for many lines.

I want to extract the data between 'FIRST some string 1' and 'SECOND some string 2', and plot this data. When that is done, I want to do the same for the data between 'FIRST some string 3' and 'SECOND some string 4' (thus also plot the data). All the 'FIRST some string ..' are stored in strings1 list and all the 'SECOND some string ..' are stored in strings2 list.

To decrease computational time, I would like to modify the code such that after the first iteration, it knows that it can start from line with string 'some string 2' and not from 'the first line' AND also that when during the first iteration, it knows that it can stop the first iteration when it has found 'SECOND some string 2'.

Does anyone how to do this? Please let me know when something is unclear.

Comment: you could try to solve the problem first before asking us to do it for you, and also provide input and output requirements.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've tried to solve the problem myself but wasn't able to do so. I've also Googled a lot but that didn't help either. What do you mean by input and output requirements?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  If you provide a sample of the input file as an [MCVE], and clarify what is the expected result, it'll probably help you get some answers.  If your attempt encountered any error it would be helpful to post the error details as well.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is you're reopening your files in a for loop, of course it will reiterate the files from the beginning each time.  I wouldn't `open` the files in a for loop, that's horribly inefficient.  You can load the files into memory first and then loop through `strings1`.

There are some other issues, namely here:

```
copy = False

for line in infile:
    if line == strings1[i]:
        copy = True
    elif line == strings2[i]:
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
        continue
```

The `elif copy:` line will never execute in the first iteration of the second loop because copy is only ever `True` once the `line == strings1[i]` is met.  After that condition is met, for the rest of the iterations it will *always* write the lines from `infile` to outfile.  Unless this is precisely what you're trying to achieve the logic doesn't work.

Without a full context it's hard to understand what exactly you're looking for. 
 But maybe what you want to do instead is simply this:

```
with open('infile.txt','r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if line.rstrip('\n') in strings1:
            outfile.write(line)
```

What this code is doing:

1.) Open both files into memory.
2.) Iterate through the `line`s of the `infile`.
3.) Check if the iterated `line`, stripping the trailing newline character is in the list `strings1`, assuming your `strings1` is a list that doesn't have any trailing newline characters.  If each item in `strings1` already has a trailing `\n`, then don't `rstrip` the `line`.
4.) If `line` occurs in `strings1`, write the `line` to `outfile`.

This looks to be the gist of what you're attempting.

Comment: That edit just made this an entirely different question.  Your original code seems like you're trying to write the files if a line matches values in string1, but now want to plot values from `string2`? Did you already figure out how to parse your text file to extract the values for `string1` and `string2`? I don't understand where `string1` and `string2` come from in your snippet.  Also it's still very unclear what is the end goal here as well, what is the supposed output?

Comment: No I want to extract the values, which is a grid of temperatures, between string1 and string2. When extracted, I want to plot the temperature grid and save plot as a .png. Yeah I've managed to extract the values for string1 and string2. String1 and string2 represent the simulation time (written as strings) of a certain layer. So string1 are the simulation times of layer 5 and string2 are the simulation times of layer 6. String1[1] is simulation time 0 in layer 5, string1[2] is simulation time 0.5 in layer 5. In other words, I want to extract per time step the concentration grid in layer 5.

Comment: As said, I've figured out how to extract the values for string1 and string2. I've also figured out how to plot a concentration grid. The only problem left is to write an efficient loop which extracts the concentration grids in layer 5 at all simulation times.